# How to drop a pin on Google Maps iPhone app via web link?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, url

I used to just be able to have a link to a coordinate on Google Maps, like https://maps.google.com/maps?q=35.7491455078125,139.382995605469

but now that Apple kicked out the original Maps app, and Google has re-launched another one, links like that no longer drop a pin on the maps of iOS users.

Is there a way to drop a pin on a visitor's Google Maps app with the click of a link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the official Maps URLs would work for you. In your example, this should work (and across platforms, too!):

https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=35.7491455078125,139.382995605469

You can read the full documentation at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

Answer (score -2):

Replace http://maps.google.com with http://maps.apple.com, hopefully that works!

Comment: Well, well... my original link works... sort of. The first time a user taps the link, they will get the Google Maps website. However, at the top of the site, if they have the Google Maps app installed, it will have a button to "always open in the Google Maps app".

yay... but a bit annoying.